# golang os.Setenv does not work in cgo C.dlopen?

Tags: c++, linux, go, cgo, dlopen

For some reason, I can not set $LD_LIBRARY_PATH to global env. I try to set it up in golang code use os.Setenv.

```golang
os.Setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", my_library_paths)

lib := C.dlopen(C.CString(libpath), C.RTLD_LAZY)
```

I use another C++ function to get `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, it shows corretly.
But lib returns '<nil>', and C.dlerror() shows

```sh
>> %!(EXTRA string=libhasp_linux_x86_64_demo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Means $LD_LIBRARY_PATH does not work in dlopen, cgo can not find depend libraries.

I don't know why.Hope some one can help me.Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], people shouldn't have to guess anything of what you were doing. In particular, question is whether this is actually related to the use of C++, Linux-specific APIs or `dlopen()`. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: For `dlopen()` can you search the path manually and open the file you want by providing a full path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to call `os.Setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", ...)` and then `C.dlopen()` from *within the same process*.

From the man page [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

> Otherwise, the dynamic linker searches for the object as follows
>
> ...
>
> If, at the time that the program was started, the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was defined to contain a colon-separated list of directories, then these are searched.

The key phrase being, *at the time the program is started*. We can see in the implementation for `dlopen` in the [glibc source elf/dl-load.c](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=elf/dl-load.c;h=650e4edc35e5e582652c1167f4275a93e8c33120;hb=HEAD#l2171) that it looks at a global variable `__rtld_env_path_list.dirs` that has already been set when searching for libraries to load; it does *not* look at the current value of `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

If you want to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to find things in `C.dlopen`, then you'll need to set it before your process starts (by running e.g. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/path go run my-app.go`).

Answer (score 0):

As KJ Tsanaktsidis correctly answered, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` has no effect after the process has started; you must set it *before* starting the process.

A common technique is to examine current value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and if it's not to your liking, set it to new value *and* re-`exec` the process.

That said, it's not clear why you *want* set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the first place. `dlopen` will happily open a library which is not on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you invoke `dlopen` with absolute path. That is, instead of doing this:

> `os.Setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", my_library_paths)`
> `lib := C.dlopen(C.CString(libpath), C.RTLD_LAZY)`

do this:

```
  lib := C.dlopen(C.CString(absolute_path_to_library), C.RTLD_LAZY)
```